# Simple date format after formatting showing the month as 30 instead of correct month

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am having date object of "valueDate" "Wed May 08 05:30:00 IST 2013" in java.I am using simpleDateFormat of "yyyy-mm-dd" format.But after formatting i am getting result as "2013-30-08" instead "2013-05-08". What i am doing wrong. can anyone help me in this?

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");                   

String formattedValue= dateFormat.format(valueDate);
```

Comment: it's MM for month and mm for minutes. look at that : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use uppercase 'M' for month:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

As you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

m is for minute
M is for month

Answer (score 1):

dateformat is case sensitive. mm means minute, try MM

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html